# Passing List (Of ChildClass) as parameter to method expecting List (Of ParentClass)?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, list, .net-2.0, parameter-passing

I have implemented inheritance for two parent classes called **Table** and **Field**. Each parent class has several child classes. In the **Table** parent class, I created a method that expects parameter **List(Of Field)**.

I get an error when trying to pass in parameter **List(Of ChildField)** to the method that expects a parameter of **List(Of Field)**. The error message is as below:

> Value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   com.hlb.icisbatch.data.ChildField)'
>   cannot be converted to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of
>   com.hlb.icisbatch.data.Field)'

My question, is it possible to pass in list of child class as parameter? If it is not a list then it works fine. But somehow it is not possible with lists?

Below is sample class structure:

```
    Table              Field
      |                  |
  ChildTable         ChildField
```

I have a method in the parent class:

```
Public Class Table

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub setFields(ByVal list As List(Of Field)
       'Do work here'
    End Sub

 End Class
```

and method in child class:

```
Public Class ChildTable

    Public Sub New(ByVal list As List(Of ChildField)
       setFields(ChildField)
    End Sub

 End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible - and for good reason. Consider what would happen if the calling code tried to add an instance of `Field` (or some other derived class) to the list. Bad stuff would happen.

In .NET 4 (and presumably VB10) this is possible via covariance and contravariance of generic delegates and interfaces (not classes) - but only where it's safe. So `IList(Of T)` is *not* variant (because values go "in" and "out" of the API); `IEnumerable(Of T)` is covariant (so there's a conversion from `IEnumerable(Of String)` to `IEnumerable(Of Object)`) and `IComparer(Of T)` is contravariant (so there's a conversion from `IComparer(Of Object)` to `IComparer(Of String)` for example).

(This ability has actually been in the CLR since v2.0, but it's only surfaced in the languages and framework for .NET 4.)

Answer (score 0):

So, for .Net 4.0+ (possibly earlier versions too) you'd have to alter your setFields method:

```
Public Overridable Sub setFields(As T Of Field)(ByVal list As List(Of T)
   'Do work here'
End Sub
```

Then when you call it with:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal list As List(Of ChildField)
   setFields(list)
End Sub
```

it is essentially calling:

```
setFields(Of ChildField)(list)
```

which means that the setFields knows it is dealing with a list of ChildField objects and won't let anyone do anything naughty like add a different ChildNumber2Field object.

Although generics were introduced in .Net 2.0, I'm not sure exactly how advanced that version was wrt doing this kind of thing.